# PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement and BEGIN/END

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

My goal is to develop a stored procedure that loops through dates from start to end dates and uses those dates in a WHERE clause. To achieve this goal, I wanted to start small and first get a list of the dates. Then, I would convert those dates into variables. I've gone through many examples, but seem to get stuck on how block code is implemented in Oracle SQL Developer (11.2; 4.1.3)

I am trying to better understand why this works:

```
SPOOL "C:\temp\selected_dates.csv";
  SELECT 
      ROWNUM - 1 + TO_DATE('2018-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS selected_dates
  --INTO table_var
  FROM
      SYS.ALL_OBJECTS
  WHERE
      ROWNUM < TO_DATE('2018-08-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
          - TO_DATE('2018-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          + 2
  ;
/
SPOOL OFF;
```

However, I receive

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

when I add BEGIN/END:

```
SPOOL "C:\temp\selected_dates.csv";
BEGIN
  SELECT 
      ROWNUM - 1 + TO_DATE('2018-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS selected_dates
  --INTO table_var
  FROM
      SYS.ALL_OBJECTS
  WHERE
      ROWNUM < TO_DATE('2018-08-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
          - TO_DATE('2018-08-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
          + 2
  ;
END;
/
SPOOL OFF;
```

Comment: Because begin/end makes in PL/SQL, not SQL. [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/SELECT-INTO-statement.html). I don't follow what you're trying to do though; you want a list of dates and then you'll do a separate query for each date? Why not just query the whole date range at once?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for the reply. I want to be able to create a stored procedure that creates a csv files for each specified date from start date to end date. `CREATE STORED PROCEDURE (start_date, end_date) AS SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_date_column = date1` This is incomplete, but I wanted to work my way up. How would you create a procedure that exports a csv for each date within a range?

Comment: Well, `spool` is a client/IDE command so you can't use that from within PL/SQL. And any file manipulation you do through PL/SQL (via `utl_file`) will be on the DB server, not on your client PC (assuming they are different machines - are they?). If it has to be on the client then it might be easier to create a single file that includes the date and post-process that into multiple files. Otherwise you're looking at generating a script file from your date range and running that. It depends where the files need to be created though (client/server).

Comment: Yes, I want to generate the files on the client side. So, I took the second approach and used `DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE();` to generate the SQL script. This produces exactly what I needed. Thanks for the assistance!..Now, I'm researching how to read files from the client side. The actual queries I want to run are large enough that I rather separate it from the `DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE();` script that generates it..Talking through this problem with you has helped a lot.